# Demons algorithm for image registration (for dummies)

Tags: algorithm, opencv, image-processing, computer-vision

I was trying to make a application that compares the difference between 2 images in java with opencv. After trying various approaches I came across the algorithm called [Demons algorithm](http://citeseerx.ist.psu.edu/viewdoc/download?doi=10.1.1.35.2299&rep=rep1&type=pdf).

To me it seems to give the difference of images by some transformation on each place. But I couldn't understand it since the references I found were too complex for me.

Even the demons algorithm does not do what I need I'm interested in learning it.

Can any one explain simply what happens in the demons algorithm and how to write a simple code to use that algorithm on 2 images.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

I can give you an overview of general algorithms for deformable image registration, demons is one of them

There are 3 components of the algorithm, a similarity metric, a transformation model and an optimization algorithm.

A similarity metric is used to compute pixel based / patch based similarity between pixels/patches. Common similarity measures are SSD, normalized cross correlation for mono-modal images while information theoretic measures like mutual information are used in the case of multi-modal image registration.

In the case of deformable registration, they generally have a regular grid super-imposed over the image and the grid is deformed by solving an optimization problem which is formulated such that the similarity metric and the smoothness penalty imposed over the transformation is minimized. In deformable registration, once there are deformations over the grid, the final transformation at the pixel level is computed using a B-Spine interpolation of the grid at the pixel level so that the transformation is smooth and continuous.

There are 2 general approaches towards solving the optimization problem, some people use discrete optimization and solve it as a MRF optimization problem while some people use gradient descent, I think demons uses gradient descent.

In case of MRF based approaches, the unary cost is the cost for deforming each node in grid and it is the similarity computed between patches, the pairwise cost which imposes the smoothness of the grid, is generally a potts/truncated quadratic potential which ensures that neighboring nodes in the grid have almost the same displacement. Once you have the unary and pairwise cost, you feed it to a MRF optimization algorithm and get the displacements at the grid level, then you use a B-Spline interpolation to compute pixel level displacement. This process is repeated in a coarse to fine fashion over several scales and also the algorithm is run many times at each scale (reducing the displacement at each node every time).

In case of gradient descent based methods, they formulate the problem with the similarity metric and the grid transformation computed over the image and then compute the gradient of the energy function which they have formulated. The energy function is minimized using iterative gradient descent, however these approaches can get stuck in a local minima and are quite slow.

Some popular methods are DROP, Elastix, itk provides some tools

Comment: Thanks for your answer. Its quite informative. Can you give some information on how to have the "similarity computed between patches" to get the deformation cost?

And can you suggest a tutorial or a resource that is useful to understand and implement these algorithms since most of the things available in internet are somewhat hard to understand.

Comment: Here are 2 tutorials from MICCAI 2010, you can have a look at them, http://campar.in.tum.de/twiki/pub/DefRegTutorial/WebHome/MICCAI_2010_Tutorial_Def_Reg_Christian.pdf http://campar.in.tum.de/twiki/pub/DefRegTutorial/WebHome/MICCAI_2010_Tutorial_Def_Reg_Darko.pdf

Answer (score 2):

If you want to know more about algorithms related to deformable image registration, I will recommend you to take a look to FAIR( guide book), FAIR is a toolbox for Matlab so you will have examples to understand the theory.

http://www.cas.mcmaster.ca/~modersit/FAIR/

Then if you want to specifically see some demon example,, here you have this other toolbox:

http://www.mathworks.es/matlabcentral/fileexchange/21451-multimodality-non-rigid-demon-algorithm-image-registration